# FB.ui send dialog box not working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, facebook, fb.ui

i'm having troubles at creating a FB.ui send dialog box when my web app is running on iPhone. Here's the code snippet, in javascript:

```
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)){
        window.top.location = "http://m.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=<<My_App_Id>>&link=<<The_Link>>&redirect_uri=<<The_Url>>&to=<<User_Id>>";
    } else{
        FB.ui({method: 'send',
            link: "<<The_Link>>",
            picture: picture,
            description: description,
            to: User_Id
        });
    }
```

It works nice when i use any browser on windows, works nice using Safari on iPad too.
But when i try to open a dialog box to send a message on iPhone, i see the following error messsages:

This dialog is not available on this device.
API Error Code: 4202
API Error Description: This dialog cannot be displayed on this device
Error Message: This method isn't supported for this display type

I've already had this error messages when I called FB.ui({}) method on iPad and, therefore, I created that if statement for treating this situation on iPad. But this workaround didn't work for iPhone.

Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 6):

This dialog can be used with the JavaScript SDK and by performing a full redirect to a URL. It is not supported on mobile devices.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

Comment: in some cases, you might want to use this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/send-button as a temporary solution :(

Comment: @GoonNguyen You should totally post that as an actual answer to this question — certainly the [Send Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/send-button) will serve my purposes and I just tested it successfully on my phone. Ping me if you do submit that as an answer so I can come upvote you :)

Comment: Thanks @OwenBlacker, I've just reposted it !

Answer (score 1):

(Just repost this one as an answer)

In some cases, you might want to use this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/send-button as a temporary solution.

Unfortunately you can't change the interface of this button.

Comment: Thanks Goon Nguyen, that's exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: "With the release of Graph API version 2.11, the Send Button is deprecated. For Graph API versions 2.10 and under, the Send Button will be supported until February 5, 2018." 

Answer (score 0):

Facebook clearly mentions that "It is not supported on mobile devices." Here is the link to their article: [enter link description here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog)

You need another way to fix it.
Even the send button is now no more supported in Facebook API.